# Default value of figure.autolayout?

Tags: matplotlib

What is the default value for rcParams.update({'figure.autolayout': True})?
I set it True and it ruined my graphs. 
Making it False didn't help much!

How can I return to my old figure layout???
I have my thesis presentation in 3days.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The default value of the rcParam `'figure.autolayout'` is `False`. 
You may find out via

```
import matplotlib as mpl
print(mpl.defaultParams["figure.autolayout"][0])
```

which prints `False`.